# Is any kind of drag-n-drop available on MS Access forms?

Tags: forms, ms-access, drag-and-drop, igrid

One of our customers needs the ability to drag-n-drop nodes of the tree inside our [iGrid](http://www.10Tec.com/) ActiveX grid control placed on an MS Access form. All techniques based on the classis drag-n-drop and OLE drag-n-drop work well with our iGrid in the "big" classic Visual Basic (VB6), but it seems none of them is available in MS Access forms.

Are there any solutions for this for MS Access?

Comment: @musefan, how can I do this?

Comment: To elaborate on @musefan's suggestion, you've only accepted answers on 1 out of 7 questions. Go thru your old questions and green check the best answers (if there are any).  We like to help but we also like reputation :)

Comment: Go to your profile, select your questions, go through each one that has one or more answers, click the "tick" to accept an answer. NOTE: You don't need to always accept answers, only accept those that actually helped you. If none helped. then maybe your 14% is just, but I doubt it

Comment: @PowerUser: I *used* to like reputation, but now I find it more of a dependency to live

Comment: Guys, now when you increased my reputation to 22, I can green some answers - could not do that without this :)

Comment: @musefan, did that - can it really help to solve the prob?

Comment: The higher your rep, the more people will be willing to help. But you have a pretty specific question, so you are likely going to need to wait a while for the right person to read this

Comment: I don't see any events like `OnDrop`, `OnDragOver` etc. in Access. This means that it is not possible using standard Access tools. But maybe someone knows how to do it using the Win32 API?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for putting that link in your post, I used it to read up on iGrid.  I'm a little intrigued by it, might even try out the demo.  But if you want to a solution that specifically uses iGrid, I think you'll have to contact them directly (SO apparently doesn't even have an iGrid tag, which usually means questions about it are rare).

Since you're talking about dragging and dropping fields onto a form, how about Access's native pivot tables?.  You can put one inside a form and let the user decide what fields to use for rows, columns, etc.

Comment: iGrid is used as a specific tree-grid container, and the customer needs to reorder the tree nodes inside the grid - so I doubt whether this native Access stuff will help. We hoped that some of the ready-to-use ideas from the online extra samples library for iGrid (http://www.10tec.com/Products/ActiveX/iGrid/Extra_Samples.aspx) might be used. It contains a series of good drag-n-drop samples which demonstrate how to drag items within one grid or between two grids.

Comment: Using http://www.10tec.com/FS/ExS/iGrid/TreeWithDependentCheckBoxes/LargePic.gif as a reference, you're saying the customer wants to drag'n'drop individual subnodes into different supernodes (i.e. move node 1.3.2 under node 1.4). How about a command button in the row called "Change supernode" that pops up a list of supernodes? It's uglier than drag'n'drop, but it would work.

Comment: to @PowerUser and others: we need real dragging so please don't put other suggestions here.

Comment: We will also need dragging nodes to another grid on the form, so any information about drag-n-drop in MS Access is welcome. Even if it will be a 3rd-party library.

Comment: Have you downloaded their demo and tried to do this task?  As a last resort, you may want to contact iGrid's developers and ask if they are willing to do add the additional feature for a reasonable fee (I've done this with other small developers before).